# Why is the consumption function concave?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

I'm reading the topic concavity in risk aversion utility function of consumption function. I'm having trouble understanding why the consumption function is assumed to be concave. I tried looking but most explained it in a way that is linked to the utility function. I need to know why on itself, the consumption function is concave. thank you so much to anyone willing to help.

Comment: What are the axes? Assuming consumption is on the vertical, then what is the horizontal axis?

Comment: the horizontal axis is wealth

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you mean here. The "consumption function" is a concept from macroeconomics, but it has disposable income, not wealth, on the horizontal axis. "Risk aversion" and "utility function" are concepts from microeconomics. Perhaps you are mixing up things here?